# How to make has many through polymorphic associations dependent in rails 3?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, polymorphic-associations, polymorphism

I have a polymorphic relationship in rails 3 and i am trying to make the through table dependent. What is the best way to handle that?

Comment: The same way you usually do it

Answer (score 0):

Would help to have some example code that you are trying this with. But the following is an example of how to get this to work.

```
class Listing < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :activity_items, :as => :source, :dependent => :destroy
end

class ActivityItem < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :source, :polymorphic => :true
end
```

That should work as expected.